# Xamarin Forms CollectionView Image source not binding to file path. (Xamarin Forms Pre-release v 4.0.0.8055-pre1)

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, filepath

If I have a simple image in the XAML:

```xml
<Image
    Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

the file path binds properly. However, if I nest the Image element inside of a CollectionView the image no longer binds.

```xml
<CollectionView
    x:Name="CV"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ThumbnailPhotos}"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Span="2" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Frame
                BorderColor="LightGray"
                CornerRadius="3"
                HasShadow="False">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition
                            Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition
                            Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image
                        Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

For testing purposes the ObservableCollection in my ViewModel looks like so:

```cs
ThumbnailPhotos = new ObservableCollection<Thumbnail>
{
    new Thumbnail(){ ImageUrl = "/Users/<myUser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68BF4E8E-DF6D-4459-B6AD-DCEDB270916B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C205001-6DFD-4846-9E6D-415F772FCB58/Documents/Defect Photos/IMG_20190102_165617/IMG_20190102_165617.jpg" } ,
    new Thumbnail(){ ImageUrl = "/Users/<myUser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68BF4E8E-DF6D-4459-B6AD-DCEDB270916B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C205001-6DFD-4846-9E6D-415F772FCB58/Documents/Defect Photos/IMG_20190102_165617/IMG_20190102_165617.jpg" } ,
    new Thumbnail(){ ImageUrl = "/Users/<myUser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68BF4E8E-DF6D-4459-B6AD-DCEDB270916B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C205001-6DFD-4846-9E6D-415F772FCB58/Documents/Defect Photos/IMG_20190102_165617/IMG_20190102_165617.jpg" } ,
    new Thumbnail(){ ImageUrl = "/Users/<myUser>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68BF4E8E-DF6D-4459-B6AD-DCEDB270916B/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C205001-6DFD-4846-9E6D-415F772FCB58/Documents/Defect Photos/IMG_20190102_165617/IMG_20190102_165617.jpg" } ,
};
```

Comment: Since this has to do with a preview release, I would say you could better open an issue at the Xamarin.Forms GitHub and see if this is a bug

Comment: Done. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4913

Comment: I answered my own question below https://stackoverflow.com/a/54090412/1823589

Answer (score 0):

The mistake appears to be the way in which the file path is constructed. On iOS I ended up using this method:

```
var docsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var photosPath = Path.Combine(docsPath, "DefectPhotos/");

        if(Directory.Exists(photosPath))
        {
            string[] photoNames = GetFileNames(photosPath, "*.jpg");

            foreach (var photoName in photoNames)
            {
                if (photoName.Contains(_item.DefectId))
                {
                    thumbnailPhotos.Add(new Thumbnail() { ImageUrl = photosPath + photoName });
                }
            }
        }
```

The critical piece is the way in which the docs path is gotten. I was testing the image path by using "get info" on the photoName I was trying to load. That file path did not work.